# Method Aws\S3\S3Client::putObject() does not exist

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, yii2

In my application i am trying to upload the image to amazon S3 bucket from local directory which is getting upload first.When i am uploading the file i am getting the error.I don't have any idea what to change.Is there anything to change or add in vendor? please help.

**Controller:**

```
$s = new Storage();
$result = $s->upload($bucket,$keyname,$filepath);
```

**models\Storage.php:**

```
<?php
namespace app\models;
use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
 
class Storage extends Model
{
 
  private $aws;
  private $s3;
 
   function __construct() {
     $this->aws = Yii::$app->awssdk->getAwsSdk();
     $this->s3 = $this->aws->createS3();
  }
  
    public function upload($bucket,$keyname,$filepath) {
        $result = $this->s3->putObject(array(
        'Bucket'       => $bucket,
        'Key'          => $keyname,
        'SourceFile'   => $filepath,
        'ContentType'  => 'text/plain',
        'ACL'          => 'public-read',
        'StorageClass' => 'REDUCED_REDUNDANCY',
        'Metadata'     => array(
            'param1' => 'value 1',
            'param2' => 'value 2'
        )
    ));
    return $result;

    }
```

The error is below:

> An Error occurred while handling another error:
>
> exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Method
> Aws\S3\S3Client::putObject() does not exist' in
> D:\xampp\htdocs\teespring-testmailer\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\ErrorHandler.php:195

Comment: Try to call `PutObject` instead of `putObject`.

Comment: no same error is coming @SiZE

Comment: Do you have this class `Aws\S3\S3Client` in your vendor and method there? What version of library do you use?

Comment: ya that is there in default..

Comment: In all the application i used like this only..There is no different between that and this code..But this code is showing error..All the parameters are correct..

Comment: that class and methods are exist in `D:\xampp\htdocs\teespring-testmailer\vendor\aws\aws-sdk-php\src\S3`  @SiZE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have given the wrong region name in **config\web.php**.That is the problem.I changed the region then it works well.

```
'awssdk' => [
            'class' => 'fedemotta\awssdk\AwsSdk',
            'credentials' => [ //you can use a different method to grant access
                'key' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
                'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
            ],
            'region' => 'us-west-2', //before 'us-east-1'
            'version' => 'latest', 
        ],
```